# Is ending one's turn considered a perceivable circumstance?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, readied-action

The rules for the **Ready** action are as follows:

> First, you decide what **perceivable circumstance** will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

**Some context:**

My group's bard got the brilliant idea to cast *minor illusion* on an Umber Hulk to surround its head in a 5x5 black cube, thereby making it impossible for party members to see it (and consequently suffer the effect of ***Confusing Gaze***) until it moves again.

We were recently debating the idea of combining this with the Ready action. The intent is to declare, "When the umber hulk ends its turn, I cast the illusion on its head, effectively neutering its Confusing Gaze round after round."

Would that be possible, or is a more in-fiction trigger required?